# Inno Setup Check additional (Windows Installer) mutex

Tags: windows-installer, inno-setup, mutex

How can I check for a mutex in Inno Setup? I want my installer to wait if a Windows Installer installation is running.

I've only found the `AppMutex` Directive in Inno Setup but this does not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`CheckForMutexes` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_checkformutexes) from the [`InitializeSetup` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=InitializeSetup).

```pascal
[Code]

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
  while CheckForMutexes('_MSIExecute') do
  begin
    MsgBox('Windows Installer Installation is running', mbError, MB_OK);
  end;

  Result := True;
end;
```

*Assuming (based on the deleted answer by @ChristopherPainter) that the `_MSIExecute` is the mutex to check for.*

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SetupMutex](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_setupmutex) directive in the [Setup] Section

```
[Setup]

SetupMutex=MySetupsMutexName,Global\MySetupsMutexName
```

**Edit:**

But it only checks for the instances of the same installer with the same mutex name

Comment: But you cannot use that to check for additional installer (Windows Installer in this case), as the error message would not match.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, thank you for your correction, I've added it to the answer